# Proper ajax call for JSON data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

First time trying to retrieve data from a JSON file and honestly have no idea how to get the objects I would like to get.

Can someone please tell me how I can grab values such as `Family Name` or `familyAttributes`? I just have no idea how to process the data.

**Current AJAX Call**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://somesite.com/EloMS.json',
    data: { category : 'Touchmonitors' },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            console.log(element);
        });
    }
});
```

**JSON Syntax:**

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "Family Name": "3201L",
      "Type": "IDS",
      "Size (inches)": 32,
      "Aspect Ratio": "16:9",
      "Part Number": "E415988",
      "Product Description": "ET3201L-8UWA-0-MT-GY-G",
      "Marketing Description": "3201L 32-inch wide LCD  Monitor, VGA, HDMI & DisplayPort video interface, 01 series enhanced AV, IntelliTouch Plus USB touch controller interface, Worldwide-version, Clear, Gray ",
      "Advance Unit Replacement": "",
      "Elo Elite": "",
      "Package Quantity": 1,
      "Minimum Order Quantity": 1,
      "List Price": 1800
    },
    { ... }
  ]
  "families": [
    {
      "category": "Touchmonitors",
      "types": [
        "Desktop",
        "Display",
        "Open Frame"
      ],
      "image": "",
      "familyAttributes": [
         {
          "type": "Display",
          "image": "",
          "families": [
            {
              "familyName": "0700L",
              "image": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        { ... }
     }
  ]
}
```

I've tried several variations of `element.category` but haven't been able to get any data other than the full objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `product` object, you'd be wanting:

```
data.products[n]["Family Name"]
```

where `n` is an integer offset into the `products` array.

For `familyAttributes` you need:

```
data.families[n].familyAttributes
```

The `["string"]` syntax is necessary in the first case because of the space character in the key.

Comment: Do you see any benefit in removing the spaces in the key's? Also - I am unsure what `index` and `element` are in the `$.each()` call, was just following an example I found.

Comment: removing the spaces would allow a more succinct syntax in your code.  The `$.each` on the outer `data` object is not much use here because you know that the two objects are called `products` and `families`.  As it happens the two arguments should actually be `key` and `value` when passed an `Object` - `index` and `element` are what you get when you call `$.each` on a jQuery collection.

Comment: Is there any point to the `data: { category: "Touchmonitors" }` it doesn't seem to do anything... What I would like to try and do is just get certain parts of the JSON file depending on when I need them

Comment: @Adjit if you don't want the whole file you have to control that from the server that generates the data.

Comment: It's a fixed file. Server never touches it or generates the data. It's already there. So really I should only need to make my ajax call once, and then use JS to grab specific parts of the data I need, right?

Comment: is there any sort of `find()` method? like `data.find("Family Name")`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use getJSON(), the documentation is here:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

You can access to your model like so:

```
$.getJSON('https://somesite.com/EloMS.json', function(data) {
    // Products table
    var products = data.products;
    // Product type
    var typeProduct = data.products[0].Type;
    // familyAttributes
    var familyAttributes = data.families[0].familyAttributes;
    // Family Name
    var familyName = data.products[0]['Family Name'];
});
```