# How to get JSON POST data in ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, post, webforms

I currently have some jquery that is POSTing data onto one of my web pages.

Right now I'm just trying to get it to post some JSON to test it out, but I can't figure out have to actually get the data in my back-end once it's posted.

I've always used `Request.Params` to get posted data, but it doesn't seem to be working this time.

This is the code I'm using to do the post:

```
// This data is just for testing purposes, doesn't actually do anything
var person = {
    name: "Bob",
    address: "123 Main St.",
    phone: "555-5555"
}

var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/example/mypage.aspx",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 0,
    success: function () {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    },
    data: person
});
```

The post is definitely successful though, as I can see it using Fiddler, plus when I check `Request.ContentLength` it returns the right number of bytes that was posted.

But I can't find the actual data anywhere.
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `data` is your data - had the same issue a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132493/proper-ajax-call-for-json-data

Comment: I need to access the data in asp.net after it's posted to my back-end service, though. The `data` object is just what I used to post the json data.

Comment: Oh I see now - would probably look into changing your `data` variable name, not sure if it's messing with things. In any event, unsure how to accomplish what you are looking for - however, take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa530946.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I'll change the variable name so it's more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Posting javascript object:

1. pass the plain object to the data option,
2. leave the contentType option alone. The default option is perfect.

Then you can access the property values of the object in the Request collection as if you have posted a form.

server side:

```
   string input;
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream)){
            input = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

## Posting Json:

1. data: JSON.stringify(person),
2. contentType: "application/json"

server side:

```
string json;
using(var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream)){
        json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
var person = Json.Decode(json);
```

Referenced from: 
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/220/posting-data-with-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-razor-web-pages

Comment: How would I do this in Web Forms?

I didn't give any back-end code just cause there really wasn't anything to look at. I was just using `Request.Params`, and putting a breakpoint in so I could fiddle around using the Immediate Window to try and find my data.

Comment: i am not sure about webforms but try adding data: JSON.stringify(data) in your ajax. and in codebehind somethign like this NameValueCollection coll;

//Load Form variables into NameValueCollection variable.
coll=Request.Form;

Comment: You might want to use webservices if that does not work. Sorry for not being much help

Comment: Hmm, still not getting anything. Thanks though.

 If I used something other than JSON, would I be able to use Request.Params like usual? Just wondering if there's any kind of work around.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, So if you want to post a JavaScript object via jQuery, pass the plain object to the data option, and leave the contentType option alone. The default option is perfect. Then you can access the property values of the object in the Request collection as if you have posted a form. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/220/posting-data-with-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-razor-web-pages

Comment: Hey Hasta, that works great! That link was really helpful. If you want to modify your answer and include what you said along with that link, I'd be happy to mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!