# while data is passed through json data in the **AJAX** string changes when it is access through stream reader

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I was trying to save an image to server using ***j query*** and ***AJAX*** but the input string replaces all the + sign with % when it is accessed through stream reader
my  ***j query*** and ***AJAX*** call is as follows

```
function saveImage() {
             var can = document.getElementById("canvas");
              var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");

        image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '')

               $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Default.aspx',
        data: { imgData: image },
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

            dataType: 'json',
    }).success(function(response) {
        alert('image saved successfully!');
    });

         }
```

and c# code is

```
 if (Request.InputStream.Length >0)
        {
            string jsonString = String.Empty;


            using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
            {
                jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd().ToString();

            }

            SaveImage(jsonString);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JSON POST data in ASP.NET Web Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175594/how-to-get-json-post-data-in-asp-net-web-forms)